# Accept enter key in JavaScript inside a text box

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox, scripting, enter

I have a script set up where someone picks a comic to go to out of the list by appending it to the URL. However, I can't for the life of me get it to accept an enter stroke while inside the text box and still maintain script functionality. Any solutions would be very very much appreciated.

Script/Form looks like this:

`function GoToURL(j) {
      window.status=('Extracting')`

```
var URLis;
 URLis = document.URLframe.Dest.value

   if (URLis == "" || URLis.length <= 0 || URLis > 20 )
       { 
     j.value = "Try Again"
      alert('Pick a comic that exists.');
         window.status=('That comic does not exist.')
           } 
    else
        {
 j.value = "Going" + URLis   
 var location=("aaw" + URLis +".html");
         this.location.href = location;
window.status=('Connecting to ' + URLis + '  Please wait........');
        }
        }
</script>

 <form name="URLframe"> 
<b>Comic #:</b> 
<input type="TEXT" name="Dest" size="5" maxlength="3">
<input type="Button" name="Go to" value="Go" onClick="GoToURL(this)">
</form>
```

Comment: Use `<label>` instead of `<b>`.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.

1. Move your `onclick="GoToURL(this)"` event handler to the form's `onsubmit` handler.
2. Change your button type to `type="submit"`.

Comment: You also might want to put the `onsubmit` out of your HTML, inside `window.onload`.